# match rows between different matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a row from a matrix of which I want to match the 2 and 3 entries (in that order and in the case below 1 and 6)  with another matrix to see whether it is present in there and which row it is in this matrix.

```
i1
1      1      6      1      2
```

should be compared to

```
      [,1] [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
[1,]    3    5 4.227097 0.0183694
[2,]    1    6 4.225503 0.0605286
[3,]    2    9 4.208603 0.1786530
```

The output should be the index in the lower matrix (indicating that the 1 6 is found in row 2 of the matrix)

Comment: @user3069326 As I have written to you earlier: you have received answers on all your 15 questions asked so far, but you haven't accepted any of them. Please do read [**what to do when someone answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [about **voting**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [about **accepting answers**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, there's not a command that matches 2 (or more) values at same time, so you need to create an auxilar variable to do it. Something like this:

```
i1 <- c(1,    1,      6,      1,      2)

data <- as.matrix(read.table(text='3    5 4.227097 0.0183694
1    6 4.225503 0.0605286
2    9 4.208603 0.1786530', header=F))

paste(i1[2:3], collapse='_') # What you are looking.
paste(data[,1], data[,2], sep='_') # Where you are looking.


which(paste(data[,1], data[,2], sep='_') %in% paste(i1[2:3], collapse='_')) # The index
```

Comment: my i1 is a row of another table i extracted how can I automate the process that it is transformedinto vector as you did manually?

Comment: not how to read in acertain variable but rather how woudl i convert somthign from a regular matrix row into the c(a,b,c,d,e,f)...you had in your post

Comment: Read only the row? `variable[row, ]`